# Converting malloc to new or std::vector

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having trouble converting malloc from my c code to c++ way of using new. I've also read about using std::vector for dynamic memory allocation. Which one is better for my case and how would you do this properly?

Current code:

```
matrix_t * matrix = (matrix_t *) malloc(sizeof(matrix_t));
```

What I've tried:

```
matrix_t * matrix = new matrix_t[matrix_t];
```

Error I got:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
    matrix_t * matrix = new matrix_t[matrix_t];
                                             ^
```

Comment: is `matrix_t` something like `typedef double[N][N] matrix_t` for some const N?

Comment: It would help to give a bit more background about the situation, and also explain why you change the current code (allocates 1 matrix) to attempting to allocate an array of matrices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
matrix_t * matrix = new matrix_t;
```

And for say an array of 100 items:

```
matrix_t * matrix = new matrix_t[100];
```

And doing the same via std::vector:

```
 std::vector<matrix_t> matrices(100);
```

although std::vector can be resized at anytime

```
 std::vector<matrix_t> matrices;
 matrices.resize(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

These days it is done as

```cpp
auto matrix = std::make_unique<matrix_t>();
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique for reference.

Comment: Is this c++14? I'm using g++ to compile, so I don't think it will allow me to use this since I can only use up to c++11.

Comment: Hmm, g++ knows even C++20. Yes, it's C++14. Before that less error-safe form `std::unique_ptr<matrix_t> matrix(new matrix_t);` was used.